# SQL Access count duplicates without ID column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have tried to make a query that created a column that incremented each time a value in a column was there more than once.

So I have:

Col1

```
99999999
99999999
88888888
88888888
88888888
77777777
```

And would like result:

```
  Col1      Col2
99999999      1
99999999      2
88888888      1
88888888      2
88888888      3
77777777      1
```

I had this SQL that could do it when I have an ID field:

```
SELECT
    m.PN,
    m.CLASS,
    m.ZAHL,
    Count(M2.id) AS IncByPN
FROM Table1 AS m
    INNER JOIN Table1 AS m2 ON m2.PN = m.PN AND m2.ID <= m.ID
WHERE m.CLASS
GROUP BY m.ID, m.CLASS, m.PN, m.ZAHL
ORDER BY m.ID
```

Now I have a table where there is no ID column in it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated query instead of a join:

```
SELECT
    m.PN,
    m.CLASS,
    m.ZAHL,
    (SELECT Count(M2.id) + 1 AS IncByPN FROM Table1 m2
     WHERE m.PN = m2.PN AND m2.ID <= m.ID)
FROM Table1 m
ORDER BY m.ID
```

Comment: @TimBeigeleisen are you sure +1 ? I used `<=` or maybe I'm missing something :S

Comment: The problem is that I don't have an ID column - could I still use this correlated query?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too familiar with access, so I don't know which functions I have available. Does `ROW_NUMBER()` exists? @Jmorte13

Comment: I don't know if it's available in Access. Is there maybe a way to add the ID column after a table is created? Then I can use the query that I already have.

Answer (score 0):

> .. make a query that created a column that incremented each time a value
>   in a column was there more than once.

You can't use a query for that, as records have no order. A table is not a spreadsheet.

But in VBA you can open a *recordset* with the orders. This will "fix" the records for this session. Then loop through the records and assign your count for each record.